# unable to browse the server throught apache

Tags: apache2

I am using apache server I typed everything is correct, but when I tried to browse the apache server through by applying server IP address. it's showing 404 not found. I don't know where I type wrong please help me.

step 1:-

```
[root@server httpd]# ll
total 16
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Mar  7 13:06 access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  203 Mar 10 23:39 apachi1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Mar 10 23:35 apachi1-error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Mar 10 23:31 apachi2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Mar 10 11:39 e1-error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4444 Mar 10 23:35 error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Mar 10 23:35 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  356 Mar 10 23:35 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Mar 10 23:35 ssl_request_log
```

step 2:-

```
[root@server ~]# cd /var/www/html/
[root@server html]# ll
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  48 Mar 10 23:33 home3.com
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  35 Mar 10 11:37 host.com
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 146 Mar  7 13:10 index.html
```

step 3:- under this config file I write this virtual host

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
<VirtualHOst *:80>
        ServerAdmin     webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/home3.com
        ServerName      192.168.37.132
        ErrorLog        /var/log/httpd/apachi1-error_log
        CustomLog       /var/log/httpd/apachi1 combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My IP address is also correct when I tried accessing it with CURL

```
[root@server ~]# curl http://192.168.37.132
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL / was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I guess this is PHP. Please share the sample code you are trying to run and also any errors that may arise. You can run in terminal `tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log` the refresh the page. Edit your question and share the output with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `ll` command you posted, it seems that `home3.com` is a file, and not a directory.

While the `DocumentRoot` directive is `/var/www/html/home3.com`.

So when accessing that IP, Apache is trying to load `/var/www/html/home3.com/index.html` which does not exist, hence the 404 error.

You need to change the `DocumentRoot` directive to `/var/www/html`, and access the page with `http://192.168.37.132/home3.com` instead. Or make `home3.com` a directory, and create an index file inside that directory.